# Convert pandas df to a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a requirement to convert a df that is in following format:

```
d = {
    'A': ['a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a1', 'a2', 'a2', 'a2', 'a2', 'a2', 'a2', 'a2', 'a2'],
    'B': ['b1', 'b1', 'b1', 'b1', 'b2', 'b2', 'b2', 'b3', 'b3', 'b3', 'b3', 'b3', 'b3', 'b4', 'b4', ],
    'C': ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'c7', 'c8', 'c9', 'c10', 'c11', 'c12', 'c13', 'c14', 'c15', ],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
    A   B   C
0   a1  b1  c1
1   a1  b1  c2
2   a1  b1  c3
3   a1  b1  c4
4   a1  b2  c5
5   a1  b2  c6
6   a1  b2  c7
7   a2  b3  c8
8   a2  b3  c9
9   a2  b3  c10
10  a2  b3  c11
11  a2  b3  c12
12  a2  b3  c13
13  a2  b4  c14
14  a2  b4  c15
```

to a dictionary in following format:

```
outDict = {
    'a1': {
        'b1': ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'],
        'b2': ['c5', 'c6', 'c7'],
    },
    'a2': {
        'b3': ['c8', 'c9', 'c10', 'c11', 'c12', 'c13'],
        'b4': ['c14', 'c15'],
    }
}
```

i.e. values in column A becomes first level key; values in column B second level keys and values in column C a list.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is another way using [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
out = {k:v.dropna().to_dict() for k,v in 
      df.pivot_table('C','B','A',aggfunc=list).items()}
```

---

```
{'a1': {'b1': ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'], 'b2': ['c5', 'c6', 'c7']},
 'a2': {'b3': ['c8', 'c9', 'c10', 'c11', 'c12', 'c13'], 'b4': ['c14', 'c15']}}
```

Comment: Great answer! I guess it should work without `rename_axis` as well?

Comment: @SayandipDutta Thanks a lot, yes I just edited to remove that , that was a part of testing :)

Answer (score 4):

This will be a little long, I dare say:

```
new_dict = {k: v['C'] for k,v in df.groupby(['A', 'B'])
                                 .agg(list).groupby(level=0)
                                 .apply(lambda df: df.xs(df.name)
                                 .to_dict()).to_dict().items()}

print(new_dict)
```

Output:

```
{
    'a1': {
        'b1': ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'],
        'b2': ['c5', 'c6', 'c7'],
    },
    'a2': {
        'b3': ['c8', 'c9', 'c10', 'c11', 'c12', 'c13'],
        'b4': ['c14', 'c15'],
    }
}
```

Unpacked:

```
>>> df.groupby(['A', 'B']).agg(list)
                                  C
A  B                               
a1 b1              [c1, c2, c3, c4]
   b2                  [c5, c6, c7]
a2 b3  [c8, c9, c10, c11, c12, c13]
   b4                    [c14, c15]
>>> df.groupby(['A', 'B']).agg(list).groupby(level=0).apply(lambda df: df.xs(df.name).to_dict())
# we groupby level 0 again, then call xs as aggregator function to access each key
# in level 0, and convert to dict
A
a1    {'C': {'b1': ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'], 'b2': [...
a2    {'C': {'b3': ['c8', 'c9', 'c10', 'c11', 'c12',...
dtype: object

>>> df.groupby(['A', 'B']).agg(list).groupby(level=0).apply(lambda df: df.xs(df.name).to_dict()).to_dict()

{'a1': {'C': {'b1': ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'], 'b2': ['c5', 'c6', 'c7']}},
 'a2': {'C': {'b3': ['c8', 'c9', 'c10', 'c11', 'c12', 'c13'],
   'b4': ['c14', 'c15']}}}

# then just using dict comp to remove column name 'C'
```

Answer (score 2):

A recursive solution seems pretty natural and works for any number of columns. We `groupby` on the leftmost column and recursively convert the remaining columns to the desired format. If only one column is left, a list is returned.

```
def df2dict_rec(df):
  if df.shape[1] == 1:
    return df.values[:,0].tolist()
  else:
    return {k: df2dict_rec(df_k.iloc[:,1:]) for k, df_k in df.groupby(df.columns[0])}


res = df2dict_rec(df)
# {'a1': {'b1': ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'], 'b2': ['c5', 'c6', 'c7']},
#  'a2': {'b3': ['c8', 'c9', 'c10', 'c11', 'c12', 'c13'], 'b4': ['c14', 'c15']}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any enhancements will be welcome

```
dictLevel1 = {}
dictLevel2 = {}
for b,c in zip(list(df['B']),list(df['C'])):
    try:
        dictLevel2[b].append(c)
    except KeyError:
        dictLevel2[b] = [c]
for a,b in zip(list(df['A']),list(df['B'])):
    try:
        dictLevel1[a].update({b:dictLevel2[b]})
    except:
        dictLevel1[a] = {b: dictLevel2[b]}
print(dictLevel1)
```

Output

```
{'a1': {'b1': ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'], 'b2': ['c5', 'c6', 'c7']}, 'a2': {'b3': ['c8', 'c9', 'c10', 'c11', 'c12', 'c13'], 'b4': ['c14', 'c15']}}
```